# Bootstrap 4 broke my jQuery fadeOut / fadeIn function?

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to test something with Bootstrap and as i imported the script from the cdn, it broke my jQuery function that fades out & In some content on the website. It actually still does the FadeIn, but not the FadeOut (which happens before the fadeIn, see below).

In any case, here's the code i use :

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  
  $("#home, #web, #design").click(function(){
    $("#main").finish().fadeOut("slow");
    $("#main").fadeIn("slow");
  });
});
```

And this is from the CDN that i added :

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ho+j7jyWK8fNQe+A12Hb8AhRq26LrZ/JpcUGGOn+Y7RsweNrtN/tE3MoK7ZeZDyx" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Also i had this jquery script before, i realized i kept it too in my head :

```html
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Probably why there's a conflict, but unsure how to resolve this.

Thank you.

Comment: do you get any errors in console?

Comment: Oh you're right, i did not check...i do get an error!
"Uncaught TypeError: $(...).finish is not a function" https://puu.sh/GXoqQ/6ce08cfefd.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check the [jQuery downloads page](https://jquery.com/download/) you can read the following:

> You can also use the slim build, which excludes the ajax and effects modules:

The slim version of jQuery does not include those functions. You must use the min version instead

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Oh no..
Thank you for the heads up, i didn't know about this.
Bootstrap seems to be using the slim version only? Is there any way to use the min version with Bootstrap 4?

Comment: I assume the slim version will only differ from the min excluding the transitions, so you shouldn't run into any issue by ussing the min version. I added the snippet for the min

Comment: Thank you so much! It works flawlessly, i had that one before but probably placed it wrong in the html, have a good day.